# About answers that just add to other answers

Tags: discussion

When reading the answers to questions here on Portuguese SE, it's possible to find answers that don't really take the question as whole, but just complements another answer by adding more information that wasn't included by anyone yet.

To be honest, I do usually do this, but only to prevent repeating the same information already told by someone, and always including an "adding to what XX said ...".

But what would be the PLSE's community opinion? Is it considered a good practice, it doesn't matter, or it should be avoided?

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: @JorgeB. Well, I don't remember any fitting examples that I could list, but I'm just asking if, in case anyone did/does that, this kind of answer would be well received.

Comment: if the answer adds something relevant to what has been said, why not?

Comment: @JorgeB. Hmm, I ask this because one day my answer wasn't well received by the asker because I didn't answered the whole question, but only added with more information to the other ones, so I kept in doubt if this is right or not.

Comment: I think the fact that "adds something relevant" is enough to say that it is welcome that kind of behavior. In help-center says "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful". That answer your question?

Comment: @JorgeB. If everyone agrees, then yes. :)

Comment: Good answer Bruno :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it doesn't matter.

If an answer is useful, it is useful regardless of whether it answers the whole question or not.
If it is not useful, it is not useful regardless (etc).

I believe that the up- and down-votes are more than adequate to control that.